# Pascal pointer to pointer SyntaxError and Incompatible types

Tags: pascal

Since there's no way to create refereces (is there?) I have to do it with a pointer to another pointer. This gives me an error:

```
type
  PNode = ^TNode;
  TNode = record
    char: char;
    next: PNode;
    children: PNode;
  end;

  PPNode = ^PNode; 
var
    current_node: PPNode;  
function find_or_insert_peer(var node: PNode; character: char): PNode; 

current_node := @find_or_insert_peer(current_node^, character)^.children;

x.pas(121,23) Error: Incompatible types: got "<address of function(var PNode;Char):^TNode;Register>" expected "PPNode"
x.pas(121,43) Fatal: Syntax error, ";" expected but "(" found
Fatal: Compilation aborted
```

I also tried this but it does not compile because of SyntaxError

```
current_node := @(find_or_insert_peer(current_node^, character)^.children);
```

**Edit**

Please help. I've even created a demo in c++ to show you this is legal. http://cpp.sh/8mxe

Comment: Why do you think you need the @ in the assignment to `current_node`?

Comment: You're trying to assign the address of the `find_or_insert_peer` function to a `PPNode`, and clearly that won't work. It's really important to actually **read the words** in the error message, which clearly tells you what the problem is and why the two types are incompatible.

Comment: @KenWhite I did, that's why I tried to add the parentheses to emphasize I want the address of the record's (the record pointer was returned by the function)  property. Than I read a sole SyntaxError

Comment: No. The solution is to stop taking the address of `find_or_insert_peer`, which means **remove the address operator (@)**. You cannot assign a function address to a PPNode. **Read the message**. Throwing a new set of parentheses around everything randomly and hoping the error goes away is seldom the solution.

Comment: @MartynA because it should be a pointer to a pointer to a future TNode which might or might not exist. Or are you asking why did I make it a pointer to a pointer?

Comment: @KenWhite Ok then I get  Error: Incompatible types: got "PNode" expected "PPNode"

Comment: So that means you need a level of dereference. What is the dereference operator in Pascal? It's not `@`, which is the **address** operator.

Comment: @KenWhite '^' but how with dereference can I make `current_node` referencing a pointer?

Comment: like this? `current_node^ := blabla`?

Comment: @MartynA I need `current_node` referencing the `find_or_insert_peer(current_node^, character)^.children` pointer. And I don't want to change the underlying pointer in `current_node^`. So `current_node^ := find_or_insert_peer(current_node^, character)^.children;` is inacceptable

Comment: @MartynA I don't understand why people downvote this question. Is it because there's a simple answer? But there should be one, then. Or is it not possible in Pascal?

Comment: It's not my downvote, but maybe it's because readers think you are floundering around trying to find the correct way of doing it by trial and error, rather than thinking carefully through what you are trying to do and ho to achieve it.

Comment: @MartynA I thought that's perfectly logical, when it says that it's an address of a function, to think that the operator `@` has some strange higher priority over `.`. So I put there the parentheses. Anyway I created a demo in c++, so please, help me achieve this in Pascal (or look at the third comment above this one). Or there might be a third question on the same shit: "How to do this in Pascal http://cpp.sh/8mxe ".

Comment: @MartynA I'm using the `&` operator there, so I though `@` was its Pascal equivalent

Comment: Please, do yourself a favour and read this article about pointers in Delphi: [Addressing pointers](http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-pointers.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in a witty-called article "[Addressing pointers](http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-pointers.html)" linked in comments the `@` operator might not work properly with more complex expressions. Its equivalent `addr()` will do the trick.

```
current_node := addr(find_or_insert_peer(current_node^, character)^.children);
```