# Pascal pointer to pointer segfault

Tags: pascal

There's this tree composed of nodes with children represented as a linked list of pointers to the child nodes (= a node can have unlimited number of children). But the linked list is represented again with the same node type. Actually the `root` node and 
its peers at `next` are root nodes of another trees, so it's rather a forest (=more trees). Every node represents a character and every path in those trees is a string (in input delimited by ',' and input ends with '.'). The characters (nodes) are added so that when you traverse the paths, the strings you print will be alphabetically orderder.

But I cannot get to work the creation of the tree, segfault is returned at `{HERE SEGFAULT}`:

```
type
  PNode = ^TNode;
  TNode = record
    char: char;
    next: PNode;
    children: PNode;
  end;

  PPNode = ^PNode;

var
  character: char;
  root: PNode;
  current_node: PPNode;

function add_before(node: PNode; character: char): PNode;
begin
  new(add_before);
  add_before^.char := character;
  add_before^.next := node;
  add_before^.children := nil;
end;

function find_or_insert_peer(var node: PNode; character: char): PNode;
var last, temp: PNode;
begin
  last := nil;
  temp := node;

  while (temp <> nil) and (temp^.char < character) do
  begin
    last := temp;
    temp := temp^.next;
  end;

  if (temp <> nil) and (temp^.char = character) then
  begin
    find_or_insert_peer := temp;
  end else begin
    find_or_insert_peer := add_before(temp, character);
    if last = nil then
    begin
      node := find_or_insert_peer;
    end else begin
      last^.next := find_or_insert_peer;
    end;
  end;
end;

begin
  root := nil;
  read(character);
  while character <> '.' do
  begin
    current_node := @root;

    while (character <> ',') and (character <> '.') do
    begin
      current_node^ := find_or_insert_peer(current_node^, character)^.children;
      writeln(root^.char); {HERE SEGFAULT}
      read(character);
    end;

    if character = ',' then
      read(character);
  end;
end.
```

Input `aa,vv.`

Note that the `find_or_insert_peer` accepts a pointer to `TNode` (first the `root`) as a reference, so that it can change it to point to a correct first node (e.g. alphabetically first should be the new node, or there was no node at all).

Comment: What's the idea of `find_or_insert_peer`'s `node` parameter being a `var` parameter?

Comment: @JohnB I was just POSTing it, but the internet connection cut off

Comment: Also I couldn't think of an elegant solution without the double pointers. So you can let me know if there's one. But still I'd like to know why this does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the `SEGFAULT` because of this line:

```
current_node^ := find_or_insert_peer(current_node^, character)^.children;
```

Within the call to `find_or_insert_peer()` you modify, as intended, the content of the parameter `current_node^` (and indirectly also `root`). But then, upon return from said function you assign `children` (which is `nil`) to the same `current_node^` and therefore also to `root`.

The error is triggered because the content of `root` is nil.

Comment: Thanks, so how do I make `current_node` point directly to the the following pointer: `find_or_insert_peer(current_node^, character)^.children`. So that `root` does not change. Now it looks like my previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41399595/pascal-pointer-to-pointer-syntaxerror-and-incompatible-types